# jQuery, highlight active menu item

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation, sprite, highlight

I am trying to make jQuery for my navigation to highlight the active menu item (my menu is made using sprites btw.) Manually adding the class="active" to one of the menu item, the highlighting works. But using my jQuery code, nothing happens...

Any ideas how to solve this?

Here is a **demo fiddle** of the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/wvEBw/1/

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="btn1"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="btn2" class="active"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS: (animated sprite)

```
//...

/* sprite menu animations */

nav a#btn1 {
    background-position:0px 0px;
    width:82px;
}

nav a#btn1:hover {
    background-position:0px -82px;
}

nav a#btn1.active {
    background-position:0px -164px;
}

nav a#btn2 {
    background-position:-108px 0px;
    width:82px;
}

nav a#btn2:hover {
    background-position:-108px -82px;
}

nav a#btn2.active {
    background-position:-108px -164px;
    outline: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("nav li").click(function() {
    $("nav li a.active").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class  
    $("a", this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab  

    $(activeTab).show(); //Fade in the active content  
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to add the jQuery library in your Fiddle
and to properly close your function with `});`

http://jsfiddle.net/wvEBw/3/

```
$("nav li").click(function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("nav li a.active").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class  
    $("a", this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab  

    // $(activeTab).show(); //Fade in the active content  
});
```

Also this article might be interesting: [Stop Misusing Return False](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/)  
Here's a quick look at the DOCS: [event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: Hi, thanks you for your solution. The thing is, that it still doesn't work in my project. I have added this library 

        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
in the <head> of my page and the jQuery script is in diffenent file, also called from the head. Any tips where the problem might be?

Comment: I found the problem! Had to wrapp the function in this $(document).ready(function() { });. Now it's working! Thank you for ur help!

Comment: @Tiii thx, yes, always always make sure the DOM is read before writing code :)

Answer (score 3):

You could also highlight navigation based on the current url with regards to your navigation href value. This way is more effective in case of redirects and when you jump directly on to the home page. Consider this example:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    function markNavActive(){
        var filename = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
        var listLinks = $('nav a');

        listLinks.each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('href') == filename) {
                // alert(filename);
                $(this).addClass('active');
                return;
            }
            if (filename == "") {
                // alert(filename);
                $('.nav a[href="index.php"]').addClass('active');
                return;
            }
        });
    }
    markNavActive();    
});
```